# How to split a variable in batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have a batch file where the user sets their name using the code

```
set /p name=
```

so say they set their name as Mitchell I then need it to be split into `%char1%=M` and `%char2%=i` etc.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you write code for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually a *couple* of ways of doing this, depending on whether you just need to process the characters or whether you need to store them for later, as suggested.

---

I'll show the first method up front since that's my usual use case for processing parts of strings (just need to process each part then throw it away. This first bit is just test code to see it in action.

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off
    set name=Michael
    call :procWithCb :callback !name!
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:callback
    echo Character is %1
    goto :eof

:procWithCb
    set procWithCbStr=%2
:procWithCbLoop
    if not "!procWithCbStr!"=="" (
        call %1 !procWithCbStr:~0,1!
        set procWithCbStr=!procWithCbStr:~1!
        goto :procWithCbLoop
    )
    goto :eof
```

You'll see that the main bit calls the function `procWithCb`, providing both a callback function and the string to process. It will extract each character from the string in turn, and give that to the callback (which you can make arbitrarily complex), to do with as it pleases:

```
Character is M
Character is i
Character is c
Character is h
Character is a
Character is e
Character is l
```

---

The second method is more akin to what you've asked for, storing each character into a set variable name, though I've also set a count variable for you as well in case you already have variables of that form set. The first bit is identical except that it calls a different processing routing and outputs all the created variables afterwards:

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off
    set name=Michael
    call :procToVars !name!
    set character_
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:procToVars
    set procToVarsStr=%1
    set pos=0
:procToVarsLoop
    if not "%procToVarsStr%"=="" (
        set /a "pos = pos + 1"
        set character_count=!pos!
        set character_!pos!=!procToVarsStr:~0,1!
        set procToVarsStr=!procToVarsStr:~1!
        goto :procToVarsLoop
    )
    goto :eof
```

Running this script shows you the results:

```
character_1=M
character_2=i
character_3=c
character_4=h
character_5=a
character_6=e
character_7=l
character_count=7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use %char?% from char0:

```
IF NOT DEFINED name GOTO :EOF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "left=!name!"
SET "len=0"

:loop
SET "left=!left:~0,-1!"
IF NOT "!left!"=="" SET /A "len+=1" && GOTO loop

FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,!len!) DO SET "char%%i=!name:~%%i,1!"

REM Other commands using char0 to charX. For verification output them all.
SET char & PAUSE

REM The environment variables char0 to charX do not exist anymore after next line.
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer It is aprreciated